# Send automated email for specific value of a drop down column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried many different codes to send an email alert when column F in my Google sheet has the value "Yes". I am selecting this value from a drop down. But no emails are sent. I have tried different emails also. Nothing works. This is the code I am trying right now.

```
function Email(e) {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("FY");
  var row = s.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var status = s.getRange(row,6).getValue();
  var subject = 'subject';   var message = 'body';
  var email ="";
  if (e.value === "Yes" && e.range.getColumn() === 6) {
   GmailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message); 
  }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an installed trigger [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to use this on edit script.

Go to 'Edit' -> 'Current project's triggers' and set a trigger as shown below.

[image: onEdit trigger]

Code:

```
function onEdit(e){
   var getRange = e.range;
   var getValue = getRange.getValue();
   var getCol = getRange.getColumn();

    if(getValue == "Yes" && getCol == 6){
       var subject = 'subject';
       var message = 'body';
       var email = "---------------";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you input James! But Its not sending any emails even after setting trigger and changing the code as above. I think Its not sending any emails at all. The error is "Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: Are you using the run or debugger button in the script editor to test the code?? When using an onEdit(e) trigger the parameter e only receives information when the spreadsheet is edited,  so the only way to test the script is by typing/ deleting something in the sheet.

Comment: I tested it by editing the spreadsheet. But nothing happens when I do that.

Comment: Can you share your sheet with me? jamesd at nairongschool.com

Comment: Hey james it worked after some editing. Here is the code ,                   function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnToCheck = 6;
  
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToCheck && editedCell.getValue().toUpperCase().trim()=="YES"){   
    var subject = "subject line";
    var body = "msg body";
    var email = ""
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
   
    Browser.msgBox("sent");
  }
}

Comment: @Diksha My code works fine, the only difference I can see is that your code will accept any form of yes i.e. yes Yes YES yEs e.t.c. My code requires that it be in the form 'Yes', like you had in your code in the OP `if (e.value === "Yes" && e.range.getColumn() === 6) {`